# Avoid multiple definition linker error when not using the redefined symbols

Tags: c++, g++

I try to build an executable that links to various shared and static libraries. It turns out that two of the static libraries both define the same symbol, which results in a multiple definition linker error. My executable doesn't use this symbol so it's not really a concern.

I can avoid the error by adding the `--allow-multiple-definitions` flag but that seems like a nuclear option. I would like the linker to complain if I try to use a multiple-time defined symbol.

Is there a way to tell the linker "complain for multiple definitions only if the symbol is used"? Or alternatively tell it, "from lib ABC ignore symbol XYZ". I am developing with g++ on linux.

Comment: Namespaces for the libraries is not an option?

Comment: The libs are developed by different teams, so code changes are impractical in this case.

Comment: I know that one. I once had to deal with three different uint64s. One of them was `typedef`ed to `unsigned int`. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have a one variant of the problem or a different variant,
depending on facts whose relevance you haven't yet considered. Or possibly you have a mixture of both, so I'll walk through a solution to each variant.

You should be familiar with the nature of static libraries and how they are consumed in linkage,
[as summarised here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-libraries/info)

#### The Superflous Globals Symbols Variant

Here are a couple of source files and a header file:

**one.cpp**

```
#include <onetwo.h>

int clash = 1;

int get_one()
{
    return clash;
}
```

**two.cpp**

```
#include <onetwo.h>

int get_two()
{
    return 2;
}
```

**onetwo.h**

```
#pragma once

extern int get_one();
extern int get_two();
```

These have been built into a static library `libonetwo.a`

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -I. -c one.cpp two.cpp
$ ar rcs libonetwo.a one.o two.o
```

whose intended API is defined in `onetwo.h`

Simarily, some other source files and a header have been
built into a static libary `libfourfive.a` whose intended API
is defined in `fourfive.h`

**four.cpp**

```
#include <fourfive.h>

int clash = 4;

int get_four()
{
    return clash;
}
```

**five.cpp**

```
#include <fourfive.h>

int get_five()
{
    return 5;
}
```

**fourfive.h**

```
#pragma once

extern int get_four();
extern int get_five();
```

And here's the source of a program that depends on both libraries:

**prog.cpp**

```
#include <onetwo.h>
#include <fourfive.h>

int main()
{
    return get_one() + get_four();
}
```

which we try to build like so:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -I. -c prog.cpp
$ g++ -o prog prog.o -L. -lonetwo -lfourfive
/usr/bin/ld: ./libfourfive.a(four.o):(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `clash'; ./libonetwo.a(one.o):(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

encountering a name-collision for the symbol `clash`, because it is globally defined in two of the
object files that the linkage requires, `one.o` and `four.o`:

```
$ readelf -s libonetwo.a libfourfive.a | egrep '(File|Symbol|OBJECT|FUNC)'
File: libonetwo.a(one.o)
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 11 entries:
     9: 0000000000000000     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 clash
    10: 0000000000000000    16 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _Z7get_onev
File: libonetwo.a(two.o)
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 10 entries:
     9: 0000000000000000    15 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _Z7get_twov
File: libfourfive.a(four.o)
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 11 entries:
     9: 0000000000000000     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 clash
    10: 0000000000000000    16 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _Z8get_fourv
File: libfourfive.a(five.o)
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 10 entries:
     9: 0000000000000000    15 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _Z8get_fivev
```

The problem symbol `clash` is not referenced in our own code, `prog.(cpp|o)`. You wondered:

> Is there a way to tell the linker "complain for multiple definitions only if the symbol is used"?

No there isn't, but that's immaterial. `one.o` would not have been extracted from `libonetwo.a`
and linked into the program if the linker didn't need it to resolve some symbol. It needed it
to resolve `get_one`. Likewise it only linked `four.o` because it's needed to resolve `get_four`.
So the colliding definitions of `clash` are in the linkage. And although `prog.o` doesn't use `clash`,
it does use `get_one`, which uses `clash` and which *intends* to use the defintion of `clash` in `one.o`.
Likewise `prog.o` uses `get_four`, which uses `clash` and intends to use the different definition in `four.o`.

Even if `clash` *was* unused by each libary as well as the program, the fact that it is defined
in multiple object files that must be linked into the program means that the program will contain
multiple definitions of it, and only `--allow-multiple-definitions` will allow that.

In that light you'll also see that:

> Or alternatively [is there a way to] tell it, "from lib ABC ignore symbol XYZ".

in general won't fly. If we could tell the linker to ignore (say) the definition of `clash`
in `four.o` and resolve the symbol everywhere to the definition in `one.o` (the only other candidate) then `get_four()` would return 1 instead of 4 in our program. That
is in fact the effect of `--allow-multiple-definitions`, since it causes the first definition
in the linkage to be used.

By inspection of the source code of `libonetwo.a` (or `libfourfive.a`) we can fairly confidently spot the root
cause of the problem. The symbol `clash` has been left with external linkage where
it only needed internal linkage, since it isn't declared in the associated
header file and is referenced nowhere in the libary except
in the file where it's defined. The offending source files should have written:

**one_good.cpp**

```
#include <onetwo.h>

namespace {
    int clash = 1;
}

int get_one()
{
    return clash;
}
```

**four_good.cpp**

```
#include <fourfive.h>

namespace {
    int clash = 4;
}

int get_four()
{
    return clash;
}
```

and all would be good:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -I. -c one_good.cpp four_good.cpp
$ readelf -s one_good.o four_good.o | egrep '(File|Symbol|OBJECT|FUNC)'
File: one_good.o
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 11 entries:
     5: 0000000000000000     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_15clashE
    10: 0000000000000000    16 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _Z7get_onev
File: four_good.o
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 11 entries:
     5: 0000000000000000     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_15clashE
    10: 0000000000000000    16 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _Z8get_fourv

$ g++ -o prog prog.o one_good.o four_good.o
$./prog; echo $?
5
```

Since re-writing the source code like that is not a option, we have to modify the object files to the
same effect. The tool for this is [`objcopy`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/objcopy).

```
$ objcopy --localize-symbol=clash libonetwo.a libonetwo_good.a
```

This command has the same effect as running:

```
$ objcopy --localize-symbol=clash orig.o fixed.o
```

on each of the object files `libonetwo(orig.o)` to output a fixed object file `fixed.o`,
and archiving all the `fixed.o` files in a new static library `libonetwo_good.a`. And the
effect of `--localize-symbol=clash`, on each object file, is to change the linkage of
the symbol `clash`, if defined, from external (`GLOBAL`) to internal (`LOCAL)`:

```
$ readelf -s libonetwo_good.a | egrep '(File|Symbol|OBJECT|FUNC)'
File: libonetwo_good.a(one.o)
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 11 entries:
     9: 0000000000000000     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 clash
    10: 0000000000000000    16 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _Z7get_onev
File: libonetwo_good.a(two.o)
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 10 entries:
```

Now the linker cannot see the `LOCAL` definition of `clash` in `libonetwo_good.a(one.o)`.

That's sufficient to head off the multiple definition error, but since `libfourfive.a` has
the same defect, we'll fix it too:

```
$ objcopy --localize-symbol=clash libfourfive.a libfourfive_good.a
```

And then we can relink `prog` successfully, using the fixed libraries.

```
$ g++ -o prog prog.o -L. -lonetwo_good -lfourfive_good
$ ./prog; echo $?
5
```

#### The Global Symbols Deadlock Variant

In this scenario, the sources and headers for `libonetwo.a` are:

**one.cpp**

```
#include <onetwo.h>
#include "priv_onetwo.h"

int inc_one()
{
    return inc(clash);
}
```

**two.cpp**

```
#include <onetwo.h>
#include "priv_onetwo.h"

int inc_two()
{
    return inc(clash + 1);
}
```

**priv_onetwo.cpp**

```
#include "priv_onetwo.h"

int clash = 1;

int inc(int i)
{
    return i + 1;
}
```

**priv_onetwo.h**

```
#pragma once

extern int clash;
extern int inc(int);
```

**onetwo.h**

```
#pragma once

extern int inc_one();
extern int inc_two();
```

And for `libfourfive.a` they are:

**four.cpp**

```
#include <fourfive.h>
#include "priv_fourfive.h"

int dec_four()
{
    return dec(clash);
}
```

**five.cpp**

```
#include <fourfive.h>
#include "priv_fourfive.h"

int dec_five()
{
    return dec(clash + 1);
}
```

**priv_fourfive.cpp**

```
#include "priv_fourfive.h"

int clash = 4;

int dec(int i)
{
    return i - 1;
}
```

**priv_fourfive.h**

```
#pragma once

extern int clash;
extern int dec(int);
```

**fourfive.h**

```
#pragma once

extern int dec_four();
extern int dec_five();
```

Each of these libraries is built with some common internals defined
in a source file - (`priv_onetwo.cpp`|`priv_fourfive.cpp`)
- and these internals are globally declared for building the library through a private header
- (`priv_onetwo.h`|`priv_fourfive.h`) - that is not distributed with the library.
They are undocumented symbols but nevertheless exposed to the linker.

Now there are two files in each library make that undefined (`UND`) references
to the global symbol `clash`, which is defined in another file:

```
$ readelf -s libonetwo.a libfourfive.a | egrep '(File|Symbol|OBJECT|FUNC|clash)'
File: libonetwo.a(one.o)
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 13 entries:
     9: 0000000000000000    23 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _Z7inc_onev
    10: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND clash
File: libonetwo.a(two.o)
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 13 entries:
     9: 0000000000000000    26 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _Z7inc_twov
    10: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND clash
File: libonetwo.a(priv_onetwo.o)
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 11 entries:
     9: 0000000000000000     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 clash
    10: 0000000000000000    19 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _Z3inci
File: libfourfive.a(four.o)
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 13 entries:
     9: 0000000000000000    23 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _Z8dec_fourv
    10: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND clash
File: libfourfive.a(five.o)
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 13 entries:
     9: 0000000000000000    26 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _Z8dec_fivev
    10: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND clash
File: libfourfive.a(priv_fourfive.o)
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 11 entries:
     9: 0000000000000000     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 clash
    10: 0000000000000000    19 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _Z3deci
```

Our program source this time is:

**prog.cpp**

```
#include <onetwo.h>
#include <fourfive.h>

int main()
{
    return inc_one() + dec_four();
}
```

and:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -I. -c prog.cpp
$ g++ -o prog prog.o -L. -lonetwo -lfourfive
/usr/bin/ld: ./libfourfive.a(priv_fourfive.o):(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `clash'; ./libonetwo.a(priv_onetwo.o):(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

once again `clash` is multiply defined. To resolve `inc_one` in `main`, the
linker needed `one.o`, which obliged it to resolve `inc`, which made it need
`priv_onetwo.o`, which contains the first definition of `clash`. To resolve `dec_four` in `main`, the
linker needed `four.o`, which obliged it to resolve `dec`, which made it need
`priv_fourfive.o`, which contains a rival definition of `clash`.

In this scenario, it isn't a coding error in either library that `clash` has external linkage.
It needs to have external linkage. Localizing the definition of `clash` with `objcopy` in either of
`libonetwo.a(priv_onetwo.o)` or `libfourfive.a(priv_fourfive.o)` will not work. If we do
that the linkage will succeed but output a bugged program, because the linker will resolve
`clash` to the one surviving `GLOBAL` definition from the other object file: then `dec_four()`
will return 0 instead of 3 in the program, `dec_five()` will return 1 not 4 ; or else `inc_one()` will return 5 and `inc_two()` will return 6.
And if we localize *both* definitions then no definition of `clash` will be found in the
linkage of `prog` to satisfy the references in `one.o` or `four.o`, and it will fail for undefined reference to `clash`

This time `objcopy` comes to the rescue again, but with a different option<sup>1</sup>:

```
$ objcopy --redefine-sym clash=clash_onetwo libonetwo.a libonetwo_good.a
```

The effect of this command is to create a new static library `libonetwo_good.a`,
containing new object files that are pairwise the same as those in `libonetwo.a`,
except that the symbol `clash` has been everywhere replaced with `clash_onetwo`:

```
$ readelf -s libonetwo_good.a | egrep '(File|Symbol|clash)'
File: libonetwo_good.a(one.o)
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 13 entries:
    10: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND clash_onetwo
File: libonetwo_good.a(two.o)
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 13 entries:
    10: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND clash_onetwo
File: libonetwo_good.a(priv_onetwo.o)
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 11 entries:
     9: 0000000000000000     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 clash_onetwo
```

We'll do the corresponding thing with `libfourfive.a`:

```
$ objcopy --redefine-sym clash=clash_fourfive libfourfive.a libfourfive_good.a
```

Now we're good to go once more:

```
$ g++ -o prog prog.o -L. -lonetwo_good -lfourfive_good
$ ./prog; echo $?
5
```

Of the two solutions, use the fix for **The Superflous Globals Symbols Variant** if
superflous globals is what you've got, although the fix for the **The Global Symbols Deadlock Variant**
would also work. It is never desirable to tamper with object files
between compilation and linkage; it can only be unavoidable or the lesser of evils. But
if you're going to tamper with them, localizing a global symbol that should never have been global
is a more transparent tampering than changing the name of a symbol to one that
has no origin in source code.

---

[1] Don't forget that if you want to use `objcopy` with any option argument that
is a symbol in a C++ object file, you have to use the *mangled name* of the
C++ identifier than maps to the symbol. In this demo code it happens that the mangled name of the
C++ identifier `clash` is also `clash`. But if, e.g. the fully qualified identfier had
been `onetwo::clash`, its mangled name would be `_ZN6onetwo5clashE`, as reported by
`nm` or `readelf`. Conversely of course if you wished to use objcopy to change `_ZN6onetwo5clashE` in
an object file to a symbol that will demangle as `onetwo::klash`, then that symbol will
be `_ZN6onetwo5klashE`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, really appreciate the time you put. Please give me some time to read carefully through it :) Btw, just this morning I was reading another answer you posted for another linker-related question and found it very useful.

Comment: @opetroch Thanks, take you time ;)

Comment: Great answer, not only it gives a solution but also explains why what I thought might be possible, actually isn't. Thanks again! I was not aware of objcopy, pretty useful for such unfortunate situations.