# Locally redefining the implementation of a global function in C++

Tags: c++, c++03, gcc4.8

I am writing some testing code for an existing C++ application by writing a file with a `main()` function and some helper classes, and linking it to the object files of the application's other classes.  I do not have access to the source files, only to the headers and objects/libraries, which I cannot modify.

In my test code I want to output a subset of fields of a huge structure.  Unfortunately, there is already a global `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, HugeStruct const&)` function in the existing code, which dumps everything.  The function is declared in the `HugeStruct`'s header file and implemented in the corresponding source.

Is there a way to override that function only in the testing source without having the compiler and/or linker throw a fit?  It is compiled with GCC 4.8.5.

**EDIT**:

Yes, there are workarounds that I can use.

I could use a print function (as suggested in the comments), but I like the convenience of chaining the `<<` operators.

I can write a `std::string out(HugeStruct const&)` function that will output the fields to a string and use `os << out(hs)`.  This is what I currently do, but it feels like a roundabout way.

Still, I find the question interesting in the general case.

Comment: Do you want special behavior only in the test *source* (i.e. when tests directly use `<<`), or when it's used internally by the objects you link?

Comment: From C++ standard point of view: NO. But if this if this operator is exposed as function in dynamic library it is possible to inject different function. What platform (system)?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, only in the test source

Comment: @MarekR, static library on RHEL7

Comment: Why not just write a `print` function and use that?

Comment: Well... That's much simpler. Simply let go of your [preconceived notions of a solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and write a utility. Can even be a (*horror*) macro. `#define FORMAT_HUGE(str) << (str).a << (str).b`. Gives you the ability to do `cout << FORMAT_HUGE(some_obj)`.

Comment: You can make a `struct Dump{ HugeStruct const& hs; };` wrapper in your test code, and have a `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Dump d);` that dumps whatever data you are interested in. `cout << Dump(myHS) << "\n";`  If some of the data is not public and has no accessor methods, you'll be a bit stuck though.

Comment: @Eljay, this is an interesting approach.  Can it be easily overloaded or templated to be able to write `cout << Dump(whatever)` ?

Comment: Overloading may as well do `string to_string(HughStruct const&)` for all the different classes you want to output.  Templating won't be as useful because the details of what accessor methods or member variables will differ on a case by case basis.  These are basically variant implementations of what Nathan suggested with `print`.

Comment: This is what I am currently doing (see edit to the question), but I was hoping to skip the conversion to string intermediate step.

Comment: "Unfortunately", C++ has the One Definition Rule.  Basically, you are only allowed to define something one.  Anything you do that violates that is generally ill-formed, no diagnostics required.

Comment: More digging showed that shenanigans are possible but more trouble than they are worth: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61780821/181238

Comment: I will stay with the existing solution of overloaded functions that format to `std::string`.  Thank you all for your comments and advise!

Answer (score -1):

If you can modify the header, to truly override the implementation, you could:

- mark the `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, HugeStruct const&)` as inline
- implement `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, HugeStruct const&)` in a cpp
- make sure your cpp with new implementation comes after the old object file in the link command

How this works:

- `inline` tells the linker to not complain if it finds multiple definitions
- the C++ standard says it's undefined behavior if you do what I told you.

  - this means the programmer (you) cannot expect a correct program if you do that
  - practically though, (all?) linkers process the symbols left to right and override the implementation

I do not recommend this :) the `out` function is safer.

Another option I see is to use overload resolution:
You have to make sure your local `operator<<` is a better match than the library provided one.

You can do that by for example deriving from the `ostream` you use in your test file. Here I will assume you use `std::cout`.

```cpp
struct TestCout: public std::ostream{
// ...
};

TestCout& operator<<(TestCout& os, HugeStruct const&);

TestCout tcout;
tcout << huge_struct;
```

Comment: Right there in the question: I do not have access to the source files, only to the headers and objects/libraries, **which I cannot modify**.

Comment: It wasn’t clear to me from the question that the “which” refers to both headers and objects/libraries. 
Headers are arguably easier to modify than objects or libraries.